# jquery data table uncaught reference

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'GetEmpRecord.asmx/EmpRecords',
        type: 'POST',

        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: onSuccess

    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        table = $("#myTable").dataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [

              { 'data': 'userId' },
              { 'data': 'FirstName' },
              { 'data': 'LastName' },
               {
                   'data': null,
                   'render': function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<button id="' + row.id + '" onclick="hello()">Edit</button>'
                   }
               },
            ]

        });

    }
    function hello() {
        alert("he");
    }

});
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

The function hello is not triggering on click event,
how to call any function on click from rendered column of data table?

Comment: And what does this have to do with C or C++? Please don't spam with tags, especially unrelated tags. I recommend you read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your `hello` function is defined in the scope of  the ready callback function, not globally. Hence the implicit onclick handler cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'GetEmpRecord.asmx/EmpRecords',
        type: 'POST',

        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: onSuccess

    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        table = $("#myTable").dataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [

              { 'data': 'userId' },
              { 'data': 'FirstName' },
              { 'data': 'LastName' },
               {
                   'data': null,
                   'render': function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<button id="' + row.id + '" onclick="hello()">Edit</button>'
                   }
               },
            ]

        });

    }
    
    hello = function() {
      alert("he");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the code to

`hello = function() {
   alert("he");
}`

Hope this will help you.